# indicates? indicated? indicating?

Tags: grammar, writing

Given in the curve chart is the information indicates the share of the elderly (65 and over) among the total population spanning from 1940 to 2040.

Given in the curve chart is the information indicated the share of the elderly (65 and over) among the total population spanning from 1940 to 2040.

Given in the curve chart is the information indicating the share of the elderly (65 and over) among the total population spanning from 1940 to 2040.

Which one(s) is(are) correct? And why? thank you!

Comment: But don’t write like that. I am a native speaker, a scientist with a long history of academic writing. Even so, I use simple direct English to try to convey my meaning. Instead of writing nine words, starting with one that conveys no information, write “The chart shows…” (I’ve never heard of a “curve chart”.) Then follow it by “…the share…” — “information” is completely redundant. Also, remove “spanning”. If you have to ask questions like this, you should be posting on [ell.se] and you shouldn’t even attempt to write in this style. Fortunately that will produce a better result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the third, because that uses a [present participle](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/present-participle-as-adjective/), which can be an adjective modifying
"information."

The present tense "indicates" or past tense "indicated" would only work in a subordinate clause, for which you would need a subordinating conjunction:  information that indicates/indicated.  (Indicates would be better because the information still indicates and so is in present tense.)